# Password with 3 different characters from the previous password - PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, passwords, plsqldeveloper

So my task consists in a password with 3 different characters from the previous password in PL/SQL.
Here is the code:

```
IF old_password IS NOT NULL THEN
     differ := length(old_password) - length(password);

     differ := abs(differ);

       IF length(password) < length(old_password) THEN
         m := length(password);
       ELSE
         m := length(old_password);
       END IF;

       FOR i IN 1..m LOOP
         IF substr(password,i,1) != substr(old_password,i,1) THEN
           differ := differ + 1;
         END IF;
       END LOOP;

       IF differ < 3 THEN
         raise_application_error(-20011, 'Password should differ from the \
            old password by at least 3 characters');
       END IF;

   END IF;
   -- Everything is fine; return TRUE ;   
   RETURN(TRUE);
```

If my old password is "aaa" and I change it for "aaa222", it gives me an error. That's fine.

But if my old password is "aaa" and I change it for "aaa2222", it doesn't give me an error I don't know why. This should give me an error..

What's wrong? Any solutions?

Comment: What about `aa1a` versus `aaa2` ? What should it return and why ?

Comment: When I run your code with 'aaa' as the old password and 'aaa222' as the new password it completes successfully (i.e. no error). ??? [db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=70100c1658b1ced9ae5d119633d1b0f3)

Comment: It should return an error because it must have 3 different characters from the previous password. In this case, only "2" is different. But it's something wrong in this code, because it completes succesfully

Comment: You're first checking that the lengths are different. With `'aaa'` as old password and `'aaa222'` as new password. the difference in lengths is 3, so you never get into the block which starts with `IF differ < 3 THEN`. Perhaps what you want to do is to create a collection of the unique characters in each password, then compare those.

Comment: I eliminate "IF differ < 3 THEN", but I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have posted your results do not make sense, I think you have a typo in your posted code (see my comments below) , but lets analyse what the code is actually doing.

**obvious**

```
IF old_password IS NOT NULL THEN
```

**These two lines in your first case set the difference to 3 and the second case to 4 as the strings are different lengths**

```
differ := length(old_password) - length(password);
differ := abs(differ);
```

**This block in either case selects the shorter of the two passwords so will in both cases return 3 (inital password of aaa)**

```
IF length(password) < length(old_password) THEN
   m := length(password);
ELSE
   m := length(old_password);
END IF;
```

**You loop through the length of the short password and compare it character by character with the longer password in both the first three characters are aaa so match so you will not get into the if statment**

```
   FOR i IN 1..m LOOP
     IF substr(password,i,1) != substr(old_password,i,1) THEN
       differ := differ + 1;
     END IF;
   END LOOP;
```

**In you first case differ will be 3 and in your second case 4 so this will not evaluate to true unless you have <= rather than < (this is where I think you have a typo in the code you have posted)**

```
   IF differ < 3 THEN
     raise_application_error(-20011, 'Password should differ from the \
        old password by at least 3 characters');
   END IF;
END IF;
```

**Return true in both cases.**

```
-- Everything is fine; return TRUE ;   
RETURN(TRUE);
```